# Flutter flow Json search using Local state

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, dart-pub

facing a issue for adding a search element in flutter flow for Json search (for a list) can anyone with the flutter flow has experienced it and what things i need to get that configuration.

tried to connect various methords for the integration of search its telling mee for a firerstore connectuion or a api integration expecting it to work with the local state json